# electron migrate localstorage of old app to the new one

Tags: local-storage, electron

We have an electron app.

Recently we created a new version of it from scratch.
Its a new project.

We need to do some data migration from the old app's localStorage.

So `npm run dev` 2 apps they don't see each other's localStorage.

---

Is there any way I can make use of the old app localStorage?

Will localStorage be available if users update via amazon?

Comment: Basically, Electron stores the `localStorage` contents on disk. You will find them under `~/.config/your-app-name/Local Storage` on Linux and I believe `%APPDATA%\Roaming\YourAppName\Local Storage` on Windows so you should be able to just copy the files (but that will only work if the two apps use the same data layout inside their `localStorage`s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the apps both have same name in `package.json` under `build`

```
"build": {
    "productName": "myApp",
    ...
}
```

They both get same localStorage.